# Rails: Allowing different views in model to access controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and have a RESTful controller for my Finance model:

**finances_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @finances = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id] if current_user
  end

  def spending
    @finances = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id] if current_user
  end
```

This allows me to get my finances models on both **index.html.erb** and **spending.html.erb**.

However, I'd like to also add in some shared logic into both of these, such as:

```
def index
    @finances = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id] if current_user

    finance = current_user.finance
    @essentials = finance.rent.to_i +
                  finance.mortgage.to_i +
                  finance.gas.to_i +
                  finance.groceries.to_i +
                  finance.carpayment.to_i +
                  finance.carinsurance.to_i +
                  finance.othertransit.to_i +
                  finance.electric.to_i
  end
```

This means I'd have to copy this logic onto both the def index and def spending methods, which doesn't seem right. **Is there a better way to approach this with logic shared across multiple methods?**

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a class method on `Finance`:

```
class Finance
  def self.essentials(user)
    finance = user.finance
    finance.rent.to_i +
    finance.mortgage.to_i +
    finance.gas.to_i +
    finance.groceries.to_i +
    finance.carpayment.to_i +
    finance.carinsurance.to_i +
    finance.othertransit.to_i +
    finance.electric.to_i
  end
end
```

I'd put the setup for the instance variables in a `before` filter:

```
# controller

before_filter :load_finances, :only => [:index, :spending]
before_filter :load_essentials, :only => [:index, :spending]

def index
end

def spending
end

protected

def load_finances
  @finances = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id] if current_user
end

def load_essentials
  @essentials = Finance.essentials(current_user) if current_user
end
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `find_all_by_user_id' for Finance:Class